Has natural language processing/generation been attempted with kernal methods
I am curious as to whether there has been much success in the past with applying kernel methods to perform natural language processing/generation?
Rather than just numerical evidence, I'm particularly interested in any work that has been focused on generating interpretable results. The reason for this question is that I'm interested in exploring if alternative views regarding how humans read/write could be extracted from what has arisen from these learning processes.
I am aware that most natural language processing/generation has become focused on transformer/attention approaches in recent years. I am not familiar enough with the mathematics, but would also be curious regarding whether GPT methods can be reduced to kernel approaches and what intuition may have been extracted from them.
